# How can I enable a submit button and [enter] key submit action on a login form?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple login form that I created:

```
     <div ng-form="as.forms.login">

        <label for="loginUserName">
            User Name
            <i class="fa warning"
               ng-class="{'fa-exclamation-triangle': as.vloginUserName(as.forms.login.loginUserName) != 'OK'}"
               title="{{ as.vloginUserName(as.forms.login.loginUserName) }}"></i>
        </label>
        <input class="w15r"
               id="loginUserName"
               name="loginUserName"
               ng-model="as.loginUserName"
               ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 2000, 'blur': 0 } }"
               ng-minlength="3"
               ng-required
               type="text"
               value="" />

        <label for="loginPassword">
            Password
        </label>

        <input class="w15r"
               id="loginPassword"
               ng-model="as.loginPassword"
               ng-required
               type="password" />

        <button id="loginButton"
                ng-click="as.clearRegisterData(); as.login()">
            Login
        </button>

     </div>
```

I am using ng-required as both the login and password must be filled out. Is there a way that 
I can make it so that the login button is enabled only if the form fields are valid? Also how
can I make it so that the enter key does the same action as the form submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use form's validation to decide enable/disable of the submit button, and use `ng-submit` to enable enter key.

```
 <form name="myForm" ng-submit="as.clearRegisterData(); as.login()">

    <label for="loginUserName">
        User Name
        <i class="fa warning"
           ng-class="{'fa-exclamation-triangle': as.vloginUserName(as.forms.login.loginUserName) != 'OK'}"
           title="{{ as.vloginUserName(as.forms.login.loginUserName) }}"></i>
    </label>
    <input class="w15r"
           id="loginUserName"
           name="loginUserName"
           ng-model="as.loginUserName"
           ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 2000, 'blur': 0 } }"
           ng-minlength="3"
           ng-required
           type="text"
           value="" />

    <label for="loginPassword">
        Password
    </label>

    <input class="w15r"
           id="loginPassword"
           ng-model="as.loginPassword"
           ng-required
           type="password" />

    <button type="submit" id="loginButton" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">
        Login
    </button>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ng-disabled="formName.$invalid || !as.loginPassword"` attribute on the login button to disable it if the form is invalid (you'll need to add a form name).  THis is covered in the angular documentation for forms on [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

you can use the `ng-keydown` directive on the password input field to check for enter key and then check for form validity.  If you need some sample code, you can find a very basic example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown)

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Instead if using ng-click in your button, make the button a submit button and use ng-submit in the form.